# How to hash strings byte arrays and io streams in PowerShell using common hashing algorithms

Tags: powershell

How can data like strings byte arrays io streams be hash using common hashing algorithms like MD4 MD5 SHA1 etc...
I am writing a script that makes backup of drives and to prevent unnecessary copies and detecting if files become corrupted it need to hash files quickly with some hashing algorithm like MD4.
If anyone have idea how to hash files, io streams, byte arrays, strings... using any hashing algorithm please let me know. Also Get-FileHash cmdlet doesn't exist on all Windows installation I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of `[System.Security.Cryptography.MD5]`, then pass a file stream to its `ComputeHash()` method:

```bsh
function Get-MD5Sum
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [string[]]$Path
  )
  begin {
    $md5 = [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5]::Create()
  }

  process {
    foreach($filePath in $Path){
      # Resolve filesystem item
      $file = Get-Item -LiteralPath $Path

      # Skip if not a file
      if($file -isnot [System.IO.FileInfo]){
        continue
      }

      # Open a stream to read the file
      $filestream = $file.OpenRead()

      try {
        # Calculate + format hash, then output
        Write-Output $([pscustomobject]@{
          File = $file.FullName
          Hash = [BitConverter]::ToString($MD5.ComputeHash($filestream)) -replace '-'
        })
      }
      finally {
        # close file stream handle 
        $filestream.Dispose()
      }
    }
  }

  end {
    # Dispose of the hash provider
    $MD5.Dispose()
  }
}
```

Now you can calculate MD5 file hashes without `Get-FileHash`:

```
PS C:\> $fileHashes = Get-ChildItem . |Get-MD5Sum
```